# slqcmd query to restore database from disk do not work in ant exec task

Tags: sql, ant, exec, sqlcmd

I am trying whole evening in this sunday to make this one:

```
<exec executable="osql.exe" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
  <arg value="-U<user>" />
  <arg value="-P<password>" />
  <arg value="-S<server>" />
  <arg value="-QRESTORE DATABASE <database> FROM DISK='<absolute_path_to_database_backup>.bak'" />
  <arg value="-b" />
</exec>
```

As suspected, the

```
<arg line=""/>
```

also do not work. :(

into the same call, only using sqlcmd utility. Unforutinetly all I can get is the error message from ants executed sqlcmd that there is "Unexepcted attribute. Consult help -?".

```
 [exec] Sqlcmd: '-Q"RESTORE DATABASE <database> FROM DISK='<absolute_path_to_database_backup>.bak'"': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

BUILD FAILED
C:\SVN\Ver_trunk\Upgrade\build.xml:72: exec returned: 1

Actual names are replaced with <> brackes.

My PC software configuration:

> java version "1.7.0_02"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
>
> Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012

Any help highly appreciated to make the correct syntax for this sqlcmd ... :)

Comment: Try using "<arg line=..." instead.

Comment: Nop, do not work for me. Same message. :(

Comment: Try running ANT in debug mode and see how the exec task is assembing the command to the operating system.

Comment: Thanks, Marc! I did not tried it before just because I really thought it will disassemble it just like it does with osql.exe ... but I was wrong ... :( What I got now is finally something more: "Sqlcmd: Error: Connection failure. SQL Native Client is not installed correctly. To correct this, run SQL Server Setup." :D Atleast it parsed the cmdline fine ... now got to get my W7 with 2008r2 and 2012 version working ...

Comment: Interesting though that @ Jenkins ant fails on SQL2005 instance with the following:"Incorrect syntax near 'C:'" ... using <arg line..> task ... weird ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is the summary of the things I had to do to make it work ( at least from Jenkins :( ):

- use `<arg line="" />` syntax, not `<arg value="" />`
- escape path by additional /
- re-configure my workstation by suggestions here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/3a2af602-75fe-4f9c-a795-733a228e7f30/

Comment: Accepting my own answer. Thanks again, Marc!